# Updating WPF Model using dispatcher

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, modelvisual3d

I have a Visual3D object loaded from a file and displaying on screen. That works fine. I am trying to rotate it from data received in a SerialDataReceivedEventHandler - which also works fine.

When I try to rotate the model, it throws an InvalidOperationException because the thread doesn't own the object. Here's what I have:

```
QuaternionRotation3D rotation = new QuaternionRotation3D(q);
model.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
           model.Transform = new RotateTransform3D(rotation)));
```

I know I need to use the dispatcher, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume all the code you posted is called inside another thread, so you wont be able to create the  `QuaternionRotation3D` on that thread, There are a few ways to solve this but without seeing the rest of your code its hard to guess but one of these options should work.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
{
    QuaternionRotation3D rotation = new QuaternionRotation3D(q);
    model.Transform = new RotateTransform3D(rotation);
}));
```

Or if its just on the `MainWindow`

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
{
    QuaternionRotation3D rotation = new QuaternionRotation3D(q);
    model.Transform = new RotateTransform3D(rotation);
}));
```

Or if `model` is threadsafe (no Observables/dependancy properties)

```
model.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
{
    QuaternionRotation3D rotation = new QuaternionRotation3D(q);
    model.Transform = new RotateTransform3D(rotation);
}));
```